# How can I terminate a file with a newline with Astyle?

Tags: astyle

I'd like to put a newline character to the end of a file if it is not terminated properly.  Does Astyle have any option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation: [astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html)

It doesn't not have the option you are looking for.